# How to crystallize a solution of N,N-dimethylphenylalaninemethylesterhydrochloride without heating it?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, solutions

I have an aqueous solution of N,N-dimethylphenylalaninemethylesterhydrochloride and I need to crystallise it as a salt. I'm afraid of increasing the temperature or the concentration of acid due to the possibility of ester hydrolysis.

What crystallisation method would be the most efficient in this situation?

Comment: How dilute is the solution?

Answer (score 3):

This molecule is an ammonium anion with an ester side chain as a chloride salt.

The first option you have is to undertake the vacuum evaporation of the solvent at room temperature. This would should prevent any heat degradation. I do understand your point about increasing the acid because in effect you have a buffer solution.

Your second alternative is to partition into a  warm amine-ophilic non-aqueous/organic layer and crystallize from there. The method is briefly described in *Phase-Transfer Catalysis - Fundamentals, Applications, and Industrial Perspectives<sup>[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-011-0687-0)</sup>*.

An excerpt from the book:

> *b. Simple Transfer Across the Interface*    A second mechanism for anion transfer is simple anion interchange across the interface, as
> represented in the following diagram:
>
> [image: Organic and Aqueous layer]
>
> This mechanism does not require catalyst to actually leave the organic
> phase, to the extent that the interfacial area is still considered a
> part of the organic phase, but it does require the quaternary salt to
> have a dominant presence at the interface. Large water-insoluble
> quaternary salts, such as tetrahexyl- or trioctyl-methylammonium
> salts, which are predominantly (>99%) partitioned into the organic
> phase, function as catalysts mostly by anion transfer across the
> interface. However, if the quaternary cation is extremely large, the
> cation will not be frequently in the interfacial region, and then the
> reaction rate will become transfer-limited. On the other hand,
> quaternary salts that are good surfactants, such as
> $\ce{C16H33NMe3+Cl-}$, are dominantly positioned at or in the
> interfacial layer. These *accessible* quaternary salts provide for
> higher rates of anion transfer across the interface.

This research paper<sup>[[2]](https://doi.org/10.1002/jps.2600530804)</sup> goes into further details about the process.

**References:**

[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-011-0687-0): C. M. Starks; M. Halper. Basic Concepts in Phase-Transfer Catalysis. *Phase-Transfer Catalysis - Fundamentals, Applications, and Industrial Perspectives*, First Edition; Springer Netherlands: Dordrecht, 1994; pp 8.
https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-011-0687-0

[[2]](https://doi.org/10.1002/jps.2600530804): Hull, R.L. and Biles, J.A. (1964), Physical chemical study of the distribution of some amine salts between immiscible solvents. II. Complexation in the organic phase. J. Pharm. Sci., 53: 869-872.
https://doi.org/10.1002/jps.2600530804

Answer (score 2):

If you have no solid to test solubility, my first attempt would be to use an anti-solvent (which you'll need to determine empirically).  The anti-solvent for your hydrochloride salt should be miscible with water, so for ease, I would suggest starting with simple alcohols; methanol, ethanol,  2-propanol. See which gives you some solid precipitating out of solution, check purity and then work from there on concentrations or temperature if required.